# sendphoto /upload blob file to telegram in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram, telegram-bot

I would use telegram API `sendphoto` function to send photo message in Google App Script.

the photo is Blob file, which generated from `chart.getAs('image/png')`.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/

In Reference https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto, it say

> Post the file using multipart/form-data in the usual way that files
>   are uploaded via the browser

Do it mean i cannot upload using the telegram api?

If can, Can i use the below google app script to upload photo?

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXX/sendPhoto?chat_id=YYYYYYYY&photo=" + blob);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telegram will only accept either a link to an image or file upload.
Might be possible to use raw blob data to upload it directly without using any temporary file.